# How to receive 40Gbps line rate traffic without zero loss?

Tags: dpdk

My Goal is capturing incoming packet with DPDK, to do this I want to integrate DPDK library ETH API to my project to receive all incoming Packets (NIC rate:40Gbps, pkt size 1500 bytes) with zero packet loss.

I didn't  know How can I do this ?
I installed DPDK from [DPDK Quick Installation.][1]

Comment: there are many criteria what affects the packet captures, more details are to be shared from 1. primary/secondary, 2. memory pool size, 3. latency, 4. the amount of data from packet to be captured, 5. write/store interface and many more. Based on these the edit shared for question is also rejected. Can you help us understand your requirement properly?

Comment: Please note, I assume you are asking for reference or sample program which can handle 40G traffic. Hence I recommend to start with `example/skeleton` and `example/l2fwd`.

Comment: still waiting for your updates? is not your goal to capture (rather than receive). If yes, you have rejected the change suggested for the question. If no, Can you help me understand your requirement to suggest the answer

Comment: @VipinVarghese Hi Dear, I want to receive packets from NIC (40Gbps) with zero loss. I saw DPDK is the best software engine to capture packets but I can not use it. I saw `l2fwd` and `Skeleton` examples and understood that `rte_eth_rx_burst` function was for reading packets from RX queues But I could not see my packets in `pkts_burst` variable.
Can you help me How can I capture NIC Packets simply?

Comment: share zoon invite for debugging live. Please be prepared to debug with ethtool, tcpdump, dpdk-procinfo, dpdk-pdump and pktgen too,

Comment: dear share the invite to help me understand reason for the reject and actual issue in running the application. Please be ready to debug via kernel drivers too.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Hi dear, what shall I do?  I want to capture Incoming packet in my C++ project and process it.If you knew how we can resolve this problem help me.

Comment: Waiting for meeting invite

Comment: @VipinVarghese meeting invite!?! where ? and How? did you say sharezoom application?

Comment: I did not follow you `share zoom application`? there are 3 options to have debug 1. stack overflow dpdk-debug chat, 2. goole hangout or zoom invite sent from your end, 3. skype debug. Please choose the any of 3 and sent me the invite.

Comment: waiting for your update

Comment: I sent you hi in skype your name appears as `ali mahboobi`. please note you have not share meeting invite for zoom app, so I can not to follow you

Answer (score 1):

shared the debug session and showcased 4 *10gbps x710 (Fortville) is able to send 40Gbps of traffic from pkt-gen. On receiver end with `examples/skeleton` with 1 core how the total 40Gbps is received and processed.

pkt-size is 1500 as per request from @Alexanov.

Hence there is no issue in DPDK library to receive packets

Comment: @Ali if you feel the information is useful, please accept